# Caused by: com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: Query (659514) cancelled on user's request

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to save data in redshift using java code through multirow insert and getting below error.

> Caused by: com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: Query (659514) cancelled on user's request.

As per the official documentation of AWS it is mentioned

> The statement_timeout value is the maximum amount of time that a query can run before Amazon Redshift terminates it. When a statement timeout is exceeded, then queries submitted during the session are aborted with the following error message:
>
> ERROR:  Query (150) cancelled on user's request
> To verify whether a query was aborted because of a statement timeout, run following query:
>
> select * from SVL_STATEMENTTEXT where text ilike '%set%statement_timeout%to%' and pid in (select pid from STL_QUERY where query = <queryid>);

I tried to run the above query with queryid but it doesn't give any result. Also statement timeout is 0 which turn off limitation of timeout.

what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Checking for statement timeouts is a good path to look down.  The query you provided only looks for a statement_timeout set by the user with a SET command.  This is not the only way this parameter can be set nor is it the only timeout.  This parameter can be for all connections by a user through the ALTER USER command.  If you think this is the parameter causing the issue you can "SET STATEMENT_TIMEOUT TO 0;" early in your session to remove this limit.

If this doesn't fix the issue then the problem may be elsewhere.  WLM settings can timeout queries so check STL_WLM_RULE_ACTION system table to see if any were applied to your query.

Statement timeouts can also be set at the cluster level through the parameter group.  So you may want to check the parameter group for a statement_timeout setting.